# Is there any way to edit XML files in Android?

Tags: android

While using file output streams and xml serializer i have created an xml file on my sd card but now i want to open that xml file and edit a particular tag in my xml file is there any way to do it?

One more thing this  xml file is the resource file of my app and i want to  make some changes in it and then want it to again become part of the resource files of my app which is installed on my smartphone

Comment: Copy that file in PC from SD-card and then using any notepad or XML editor, you can edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a file explorer/manager like **Ghost Commander** (https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ghostsq.commander) and a file editor like **Text Edit** (https://market.android.com/details?id=org.paulmach.textedit) you can do it from your mobile